# Do buses run 24 hours a day in Barcelona?

Tags: public-transport, buses, barcelona

We have found out that the metro in Barcelona operates from 05:00 to midnight (most of the time). However we have planned a couple of trips which last longer than that. Any idea if the buses operate past midnight, or even 24hr?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like many other cities, the metros and regular buses [stop at night](http://www.tmb.cat/en/preguntes-frequents) (between midnight and 5am most nights). There is a different [night bus network](http://www.emt-amb.com/Principales/BusquedaNitBus.aspx) (*NitBus*) in [Barcelona](http://www.emt-amb.com/Uploads/PDFsGuia/201102281051377122_Guia%20Nitbus%20Barcelona.pdf) and its [suburbs](http://www.emt-amb.com/Uploads/PDFsGuia/201102281047201653_Nitbus%20%c3%80rea%20Metropolitana.pdf) with 18 lines (N0 to N17). I believe that the [fares and passes](http://www.tmb.cat/en/bitllets-i-tarifes) are the same as for the day buses.